# Why this prolog's output is yes/true?

Tags: prolog

I'd like to know why logically this is a valid inference:

```
friends(X,Y) :- like(X,Y).
friends(david,sara).

?- like(david,sara).    
yes
```

Comment: It is not. The query `like(david, sara)` will even raise an exception, because you never define this predicate. Likely there is some other part of the Prolog program that you do not show here.

Comment: Hi, Im really new to it , But that's about it .not hiding anything :)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to say that all friends like each other by virtue of friendship then it is :

```
friends(david,sara) .

like(X,Y) :- friends(X,Y) ; friends(Y,X) .
```

```
?- like(david,sara) .

yes .
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I totally understand your code , it is modus ponens if im not mistaken. But my code is different and it's still true..

Comment: Perhaps you have still old predicates loaded? Can you try to restart your Prolog environment and see if it is still ok?